# 403 при открытии изображений с i.stack.imgur.com

Tags: поддержка, статус-не-воспроизводится, imgur

Не вижу изображений в stackoverflow.com с сервера i.stack.imgur.com.
Практически все возвращают страницу 403.

[image: Изображение 1]

Изображение выше, мне не видно.

[image: Изображение 2]

А эти, сверху и снизу, загруженные мною, видны:

[image: Изображение 3]

Comment: Сейчас изображения видны? А то бывают у imgur плавающие ошибки доступа (как раз 403 и 404).

Comment: У меня всё отображается. Chromium 60.0.3112.113 x32, Windows 10 1607 x64, оператор связи — Комфортел Санкт-Петербург.

Comment: Странно, но сейчас появились. Даже которые выложены не сегодня.